# Mount command failing on 10.7.5

Tags: macos, bash, shell, mount

I have a shell script that mounts an smb share.  It works perfectly on all macs with every OS revision except 10.7.5
The offending command is simply:

```
mount -t smbfs -o nobrowse //test:test@servername/sharename /my/mnt/point
```

When I attempt this command on a 10.7.5 mac, it fails either with a "broken pipe" or "authentication failed" error.  However, it works fine on macs running 10.7.4, 10.6, 10.8 etc.

Can anyone successfully use this command on 10.7.5?
Is there any alternative way of achieving this, or troubleshooting exactly why this error is happening?  I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The problem was two fold: Firstly, for some reason you cannot run this command as root in 10.7.5, and secondly you cannot mount outisde of /Volumes.  Strangely this seems to work in all other OS revisions.   I have worked around this problem by mounting my share in /Volumes and then creating a sym link to the desired mount point:   mkdir -p /Volumes/share   sudo -u localadminuser mount -t smbfs -o nobrowse //user:pass@server/share /Volumes/share   ln -s /Volumes/share /location/that/I/prefer/to/mnt       I hope this helps someone out.  No idea why 10.7.5 changes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Thanks for the replies. The problem was two fold: firstly, for some reason you cannot run this command as root in 10.7.5, and secondly you cannot mount outisde of `/Volumes`. Strangely this seems to work in all other OS revisions. I have worked around this problem by mounting my share in `/Volumes` and then creating a sym link to the desired mount point:

```
mkdir -p /Volumes/share 
sudo -u localadminuser mount -t smbfs -o nobrowse //user:pass@server/share /Volumes/share 
ln -s /Volumes/share /location/that/I/prefer/to/mnt
```

I hope this helps someone out. No idea why 10.7.5 changes this. –  BSUK

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why the mount will not work. Some of the reasons include:

- Time between server and client being too different
- Workgroup name not specified on the mac
- Local hostname uses non-latin characters
- Encryption is too strict between the mac and the server

To solve the time; set the time.

I've seen broken pipe/authentication errors most often when you don't use a workgroup name for the connection. A connection string looking like generally works better than one without any workgroup:

```
//WORKGROUP;user:50000@192.168.2.1/Share
```

... assuming that the `50000` is the password for the user user should allow the connection. Generally, you just need to have a string before the semi-colon, it can read anything; it just needs to be there.

To solve the local hostname issue click on an interface, choose `advanced` go to the `WINS` tab and make sure that the name doesn't have any foreign characters there.

If the encryption is too strict, you will need to edit the [`nsmb.conf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/nsmb.conf.5.html). I have a set of lines looking like:

```
[server1]
minauth=none
```

for an ancient BSD server which cannot deal with encrypted passwords. You can have this in either an `/etc/nsmb.conf` or `~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf` file.

This may not address your issue, but it may help you in trying to proceed.

Unfortunately, saying it works on box x and not on box y doesn't really help, as there could be any arbitrary configuration difference between them.